# Converting a project that uses a 64 bit dll in Delphi 11 Alexandria from Delphi 10.3. Code on D11 is throwing an access violation

Tags: delphi, pascal, rad-studio, delphi-11-alexandria

I have an app that uses winrar (unrar64.dll). In delphi 10.3 the code runs fine, but running it under Delphi 11, it throws an access violation on this line

`RARSetCallback(RARArchiveInstance, HandleRarCallBack, Integer(Self));`

This function is in the dll header file as

`TRARSetCallback = procedure(hArcData: THandle; Callback: TRARUnRarCallback; UserData: longint); stdcall;`

The second param is a function defines as such

`TRARUnRarCallBack = function(msg: Cardinal; UserData, P1, P2: longint): integer; stdcall;`

I assume the data types may have changed from 10.3 to 11. but cannot figure out where the issues lie. Thank you

Comment: And how did you declare `HandleRarCallBack` yourself? Why are you casting `self` as `Integer` when the parameter should be `longint`?

Comment: This was code I inherited and trying to make sense of it, so Im unsure.  However, it was working in 10.3 but no longer does in 11.

`function HandleRarCallBack(msg: THandle; UserData, P1, P2: LongInt): integer; stdcall;
begin
  try
    Result := TRAR(UserData).OnUnRarCallBack(msg, UserData, P1, P2);
  except
    Result := -1;
  end;
end;`

Comment: Sorry, trying to figure how to code format in comments

Comment: Does it help if you change LongInt to NativeInt or pointer? I suppose UserData, P1 and P2  are pointers and LongInt is 32-bit under Win64. The cast Integer(self) shall be at least NativeInt(self) or pointer(self), depending on how you modify the callback parameter types.

Comment: Exactly. These look like pointers. Check the C header file for the dll. Make sure that you knownfor sure rather than guessing. @AmigoJack Integer and Longint are the same on Windows.

Comment: The recent Delphi version supports ASLR. You can try to disable that in the Linker options. Note that you may still have a type problem, but that can as well reside inside the DLL itself.

Comment: I don't recommend suppressing ASLR far better to fix the defects. The DLL won't be using 32 data types for pointers.

Comment: Please edit your question instead of providing code in comments. And use code **block** formatting instead of code **fragment** formatting.

Comment: @AmigoJack: Probably you meant to say `NativeInt`. As David pointed out, `LongInt` is the same as `Integer`, and doesn't vary with the pointer size.

Answer (score 4):

All of the longints declared in your code are wrong. They should be `LPARAM` which is pointer sized.

You should refer to the official header file to make sure the types are defined correctly across your code. My guess is that you have an old Pascal header translation. You can either fix it yourself or search for a new one.

Comment: It's fascinating how many issues of this type has surfaced since ASLR was enabled. The risk of *actual symptoms* of buggy code due to truncated pointers has gone from very low to very high essentially overnight.

Comment: Thank you both for the info Ill look into and update accordingly. Thanks!

Comment: Changing the Cardinal data types to THandle and the integers to LPARAM worked. Also, thanks for the info on ASLR, I figured there was some drastic change to handling of data types but was unaware of ASLR thanks for the info.

Im new here. is there a way to send a thanks or something for helping?

Comment: @RichardFragiacomo: The best thing you can do is to click the green (or maybe it's grey initially) checkmark to the left of David's answer (as soon as that one becomes available, it may take a few hours).

Comment: Cardinal -> THandle in the one arg in this question is wrong. Cardinal is fine but DWORD is how it is declared in the header. You need to read that header file.